# Arredondar cantos de um Expanded - Flutter

Tags: mobile, flutter

Estou tentando arredondar os cantos do segundo Expanded do código abaixo, no caso só queria arredondar o topLeft e o topRight dele, já tentei usar um **ClipRRect** e **BoxDecoration** mas ainda não consegui.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Calculadora());
}

class Calculadora extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue[100],
                  height: 120,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Também tentei retirar o Expanded e aplicar só no container, mas ainda assim não funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não coloque a borda no Expanded, pois ele é um Widget mais relacionado com o layout de seu Widget filho. Utilize no widget filho (no seu caso, o Container) diretamente.

Use a propriedade [borderRadius](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration/borderRadius.html) do [BoxDecoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html) que você passou para o seu `Container`. A classe BorderRadius possui um [construtor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BorderRadius/BorderRadius.only.html) que permite você escolher a borda de cada canto especificamente:

```
borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(40.0),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(40.0))
```

Isso já deve ser o suficiente para ter o comportamento que você deseja.

Uma observação: Reparei que o fundo da tela é branco, e o seu Container de baixo tinha uma cor branca, então não é possível notar a borda. (Ficaria branco no branco.) Você disse que já tinha tentado antes. Talvez isso tenha gerado um engano? Você pode colocar o fundo preto para visualizar a borda:

```
color: Colors.black, //Dentro do boxDecoration do container inferior.
```

Segue o exemplo completo, com a borda, e o fundo do container preto. Pode ser testado no [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/).

```
class Calculadora extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue[100],
                  height: 120,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(40.0),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(40.0))),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigada, funcionou perfeitamente